# How can I find more debug info for Failed building wheel for flash-attn?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

I'm installing the requirements from:

https://github.com/EleutherAI/gpt-neox/blob/5dd366539803dbf1fd725cc057013fd002a4cfd4/requirements.txt

with python3.10.10 and the error I get is:

```
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1900, in _run_ninja_build
          subprocess.run(
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 526, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ninja', '-v']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/var/tmp/pip-install-6tvvm6rt/flash-attn_a1906e2e253a41718905e14808302665/setup.py", line 201, in <module>
          setup(
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 87, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 968, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 319, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1217, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 987, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 346, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 843, in build_extensions
          build_ext.build_extensions(self)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 466, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 492, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 246, in build_extension
          _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 547, in build_extension
          objects = self.compiler.compile(
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 658, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
          _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects(
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1573, in _write_ninja_file_and_compile_objects
          _run_ninja_build(
        File "/home/aa/.pyenv/versions/3.10.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1916, in _run_ninja_build
          raise RuntimeError(message) from e
      RuntimeError: Error compiling objects for extension
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for flash-attn
```

Where can I get more info on why ninja is failing?